# Flutter firebase messaging issue on upgrade

Tags: flutter, dart

I was using `firebase_messaging 7.0.0` all is working fine but i need to update my flutter so i have upgrade firebase_messaging to 10.0.9 now its stop working on getToken.

When app load it keep crashing and showing

```
E/flutter (17162): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: [firebase_messaging/unknown] java.io.IOException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.io.IOException: FIS_AUTH_ERROR
```

I have try everything

```
flutter clean 
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.0'
```

But it's not working if I comment my getToken then my app is fine. I didn't find any solution on GitHub or StackOverflow. I have checked my google-service.json etc all is fine

Comment: Try to use BOM for firebase on android side.

Answer (score 0):

Yes now it's different.
please follow steps here:
[firebase messaging doc](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/overview/)
and you have to add [firebase_core](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_core) package to your `dependencies`
and follow this steps too: [firebase_core doc](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/overview/)